# Strange behavior encountered while using tar

Tags: linux, compression, tar

I had a folder of useless C programs for a project. When I was compressing it using tar, I kept using

`tar -cvf c-project`

and then realized I'm setting the flag for the file name and I'm giving none.

So I tried remove the flag `f` and set the command to `tar -cv c-project` assuming, the name of the tar file would become `c-project.tgz`.

However, this is what happened.

[image]

This behavior doesn't appear when gzip is used. That is the additonal `z` flag is added.

Any idea why this is happening? The contents seem to be the content of the C files. However, why are they "scrambled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify an output file, then `tar` outputs to "standard out" by default, which is typically your screen. Since the contents of a `tar` file isn't directly human-readable, this will appear to be garbage on your screen. The "standard out" behavior is useful when you pipe `tar`'s output to another program, like `tar -cv foodir | gzip > foodir.tgz`. A shorter way to accomplish the same is `tar -czvf foodir.tgz foodir`. `tar` is an old program, and its syntax is quirky for historical reasons, so you'll probably find that there are just patterns for doing common tasks that you just get used to.

Comment: If I saved the output on the screen to a text file and then used that information to create a tgz file and then extracted it, would I practically get the files again?

Comment: Your terminal program most likely wouldn't save the exact raw contents, so that probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look with more attention you may notice that you wrote

> tar -cvf c-project

It's equivalent to

> tar -cvf c -p roject

O-O-O-ps... Indeed you try to create tar archive with name c and additional option p. Such option exist. So you don't get error p - unknown option. But you try to archive dir roject. This absent object. Unfortunately I can't see you screen short. You must just enquote "c-project". And the is no problem...